# How to serve assets from S3 to Client in node.js application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-s3, assets

I want to use Amazon S3 to serve my static files (images, fonts,...) to client rather than storing them directly in the web host. I've created a bucket and uploaded my files. I've read other questions and tutorials on how to do this and I got confused since I haven't served files from external storage before.

How do I do this in a secure and standard way? I don't know if this should be done in frontend by directly including URLs to objects or having the server request the files using SDK or other options...

I'm using Node, Express and React.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

1. configure your bucket to be used to serve static content. You can find the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html).
2. configure your build process to add your static files to the react bundle.
3. build your react app and upload the dist/build folder to the root of the bucket.

That will allow you to serve your static files and your Rect App from S3. Your URL will be a little bit ugly: it will be something like: `http://bucket-name.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com`.

If you want to have a special URL, like `www,yourappname.com` you'll need to perform a few more steps:

1. You'll need to create an SSL public certificate.
2. You'll need to configure a CloudFront Distribution.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/) you can find more info about these extra steps.

**IMPORTANT**: S3 does not support Express/Node. For that, you'll need a web server.

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood my problem. I am not trying to host the whole website in S3. But rather to use S3 as external storage/database for files like images, etc... The website itself is dynamic and I'm gonna host it on a VPS.

Comment: if you upload your static files to s3 and follow the first step of my answer you will be able to make reference to your files using the s3 URL. For example, if you have an image called `background.jpg` you can make reference to it with `http://bucket-name.s3-website-region.amazonaws.com/background.jpg`. With that, the file will appear in the website.